# RoR modelling for different users, Devise, Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I have a single users table through Devise. Branching off this table are 3 other models (author.rb, seller.rb and buyer.rb) with each having a one to one relationship with the main Users table.

The reason for this is each have some unique attributes and I want to keep the main Users table tidy. I am using active admin and want to avoid redundant fields when registering a new user.

Currently I am using enums to assign user roles:

```
enum role: [:author, :sellers, :buyers]
```

The problem is when I set a role it works in the sense that I can restrict what a user sees based on that role however there is a big issue I have below.

The problem:

I want to be able to register an Author. Everything good so far. But I also want to be able to register a Buyer and then associate that buyer with the author as two different users. At the moment a user is becoming both at the same time through nested forms in active admin I used which is not what I want. I want a user to be a buyer and the other user to be an author.

Maybe I don't have my relationships set up correctly for this? Or it could be a problem in active admin?

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :author
    has_one :buyer
end
```

Basically I want to be able to register two different users and after that associate them and I don't know how to do this. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: ***I want a user to be a buyer and the other user to be an author.*** What do you mean by ***the other user***?

Comment: Sorry to clarify, when I am registering users I can choose a role, which is fine, I can restrict what a user sees where. But I can't register an author or buyer with their own individual names, emails etc. Bare in mind these core attributes are in the main users table. Only attributes unique to an author or buyer are in their tables. Currently I can register a user but can only make them both authors and buyers at the same time.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do accomplish.  A user can register an an author.  When that happens you want ANOTHER user to be AUTOMATICALY registered with the role of buyer or seller? Where does the registration information come from for this second user?  Is this really want  you want to do?

Comment: No, I just want to just be able to register two separate users with a name, email etc and their role and then be able to associate them properly. That's all.